# Nifi ETL - How to insert a JSON object to a SQL table, then get its id to insert to other reference table

Tags: transform, etl, apache-nifi

In Nifi, I get a "category" JSON record from an API, which has two keys "source_id" and "source_name". Then I used JoltTransformJson and PutSQL processors to transform and insert this record into the "category" table in MSSQL. However, the "category_id" field of this table is an auto-increment. Therefore, only the "source_name" field has been inserted into the "category".
Because of some reason, I can not alter the "category" table to add the "source_id" field. So, I created a "category_ref" table to map between "category_id" with "source_id". How can I get exactly the "category_id" value that has just been inserted into the "category" table and then insert ("category_id", "source_id") into the "category_ref" table.

Example:

Source Json Record:
{
"source_id":'101'
"source_name": "Computer"
}

I want to transform and insert into this category tables (MSSQL):

**category table:**

| Column category_id | category_name column |
| --- | --- |
| auto-increment | Computer |

And then get auto-increment value of category have just been inserted. Finally, insert into category_ref table with this value and  'source_id' value

**category_ref table:**

| Column category_id | Column source_id |
| --- | --- |
| category.category_id | 101 |
|  |  |

Comment: Set `Obtain Generated Keys`  to `true` for `PutSQL`, it will create a new attribute `sql.generated.key` for successful FlowFIles.

Comment: Does it got resolved? Please mention the approach.